# docker containerized zabbix server monitoring same host running the zabbix server : connection refused

Tags: docker, zabbix

I m running a dockerized version of zabbix server (centos 6.0) on my host. I m also running zabbix-agent2 on this host with configuration of server with ip adress of 127.0.0.1.

When i go into zabbix frontend web interface i get these error on the detected host:

When the ip is at default value 127.0.0.1:10050:

```
Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to [[127.0.0.1]:10050]: [111] Connection refused
```

When i change the default value to 172.17.0.1:10050 (the docker cant identify localhost of the host naturally) :

```
Get value from agent failed: ZBX_TCP_READ() failed: [104] Connection reset by peer
```

When i go to host and i ping or traceroute the host it works well.
When i go to host and i try detect operating system i get the error

```
Cannot execute script.
sh: sudo: command not found
```

What can i do to make the host work properly?

I have tried to check these posts :
[Access localhost from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68021524/access-localhost-from-docker-container)
(when i use 172.17.0.1).

I have tried to use `network_mode: host` but it conflicts with network being defined in the docker-compose.yml

I have tried this solution [How to use the host network, and any other user-defined network together in Docker-Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303141/how-to-use-the-host-network-and-any-other-user-defined-network-together-in-dock)
but it doesnt work either

The port of the docker-compose is well defined and mapped (10051:10051)

Comment: you need to use the public IP address (like 192.168.0.1 bind to eth0 or ens192, etc), not the local interface, because docker's local interface is different from the host one.

Comment: I have also tried with the public ip adress and it is not working either